# How to remove a character from a arraylist directly

Tags: java, arraylist

This code says

> Note: Hello.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        String s="hello";
        ArrayList<Character> al=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length() ;i++)
        {
            al.add(s.charAt(i));
            
        }
        Character ch=new Character('h');
       al.remove(ch);
        System.out.print(al);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the actual question? Does the error say in which line is the problem?

Comment: Skimming over it, `new Character` is definitely deprecated. Read its Javadoc to learn about why and alternatives.

Comment: try use `char` instead of `Character`

Comment: Here is the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#%3Cinit%3E(char)), it says: *Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory valueOf(char) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.*

Comment: I should remove the character 'h' directly using ```remove()``` method without passiing index

Comment: Why do you need that list in the first place? You can just use `replace()` on the initial string and replace `h` for an empty string

Comment: @dineshbabu - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1):

Everything except `Character ch=new Character('h')` is fine in your code.

Replace

```
Character ch=new Character('h');
```

with

```
Character ch = Character.valueOf('h');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use -

```
al.remove(Character.valueOf('h'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you should search the character in the list and retrieve its index.Then use remove method.

```
myList.remove(index);
```

Comment: Thats fine but im asking how to remove without passing index